# Wait until element is disabled

Tags: java, selenium

I use this code to click on a dropdown:

```
        // Wait element to be clickable
        WebDriverWait webDriverWait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
        webDriverWait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id(dropDownId)));

        // Click dropdown to select item
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
        WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.id(dropDownId));
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(ele));
        ele.click();
```

I get error `element click intercepted: Element...` probably because there is a layer which displayed Login bar. After that the element is disabled and the code throws exception.

Is it possible to implement a listen which waits for the element not to be disabled?

Comment: It would be helpful if you can provide URL?

Comment: It's a internal Angular application behind VPN.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for -

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("YourXpath"))).isEnabled();
```

Comment: I get `org.openqa.selenium.ElementClickInterceptedException: element click intercepted: Element <div _ngcontent-ysw-c12="" fxflex="auto" class="caption caption-component" id="equipment.select.selector-caption" style="flex: 1 1 auto; box-sizing: border-box;">...</div> is not clickable at point (493, 613). Other element would receive the click: <div _ngcontent-ysw-c9="" style="flex: 1 1 100%; box-sizing: border-box; max-width: 35%;">...</div>`